# How to unnest data with SparkR?

Tags: r, apache-spark, hive, sparkr

Using `SparkR` how can nested arrays be "exploded along"? I've tried using `explode` like so:

```
 dat <- nested_spark_df %>% 
     mutate(a=explode(metadata)) %>%
     head()
```

but though the above does not cause an exception to be thrown, it does not promote the nested fields in `metadata` to the top level. Essentially I'm seeking behavior similar to that of Hive's `LATERAL VIEW explode()` functionality without relying on a `HiveContext`.

Note that in the code snippet I'm using the NSE enabled via `SparkRext`. I think the equivalent straight-`SparkR` would be something like `... %>% mutate(a=explode(nested_spark_df$metadata)) ...` or something along those lines.

#### EDIT

I've tried using `LATERAL VIEW explode(...)` in the `SparkR::sql` function. It seems to work great with Parquet and ORC data. However when working with nested Avro data I tried:

```
dat <- collect(sql(HiveContext,
                   paste0("SELECT a.id, ax.arrival_airport, x.arrival_runway ",
                          "FROM avrodb.flight a ",  
                             "LATERAL VIEW explode(a.metadata) a AS ax ",
                          "WHERE ax.arrival_airport='ATL'")))
```

Only to get the following error, though when a swap out `avrodb` with `parquetdb` containing equivalent data it does what I expect.

```
Error in invokeJava(isStatic = TRUE, className, methodName, ...) :
  org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 4 in stage 5.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 4.3 in stage 5.0 (TID 1345, dev-dn04.myorg.org): org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Found metadata, expecting union
    at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.doAction(ResolvingDecoder.java:292)
    at org.apache.avro.io.parsing.Parser.advance(Parser.java:88)
    at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.readIndex(ResolvingDecoder.java:267)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:155)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readArray(GenericDatumReader.java:219)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:153)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:155)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readField(GenericDatumReader.java:193)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:183)
    at org.apache.avr
Calls: <Anonymous> ... collect -> collect -> .local -> callJStatic -> invokeJava
```

This despite the fact that I included the DataBricks Avro package when starting Spark. Reading the same data with spark using a `SQLContext` (instead of the `HiveContext`) works fine except that I haven't been able to figure out how to effectively use the `explode()` function. I've also confirmed that this is not an issue with the data itself by successfully querying the same files via Hive using the same HQL statement I tried running with `SparkR::sql(HiveContext, hql)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks much to @Sim. I finally figured out a sane approach though. The key is that after the `explode` operation when all the exploded values are still nested one level deep a `select` must be performed. For example:

```
dat <- nested_spark_df %>% 
 mutate(a=explode(nested_spark_df$metadata)) %>%
 select("id", "a.fld1", "a.fld2")
```

which will result in a `SparkR DataFrame` object with 3 columns: `id`, `fld1`, and `fld2` (no `a.` prepended).

My mental block was that I was trying to get explode to act like PIG's `flatten` where it would create a bunch of new field names at the top level of the schema.

Answer (score 0):

At this point, working with array columns in dplyr is tricky, e.g., see [this issue](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1846). Probably best to use `explode()` via Spark. Also note that there is overhead associated with using the DSL version of `explode` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37350297/622495)) so you may want to use the SQL form via `sql()`.

Comment: Thanks very much. My question is how to properly use `explode()` such that nested records are promoted. What goes on the LHS of the `mutate(LHS=explode(RHS))` expression such that several fields are promoted to the top level?

See my question edit addressing why the `sql()` approach has not been effective for me.

Comment: Please, include the exact SparkSQL `LATERAL VIEW` statement you use from the Spark Shell (or a notebook) but _not_ SparkR. Add to that the output of `df.printSchema`.