# How do I use mutate on DataFrame in SparkR?

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I am trying to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38602105/how-to-unnest-data-with-sparkr) method to explode a field in a dataframe using SparkR.
My code is:

```
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME="/usr/hdp/2.6.0.3-8/spark")
.libPaths(c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R", "lib"), .libPaths()))
library(SparkR)
sc <- sparkR.init(master="local")
hc <- sparkRHive.init(sc)
df <- sql(hc, "SELECT * FROM tweetsorc5")
library(tidyverse)
dat <- df %>%   mutate(a=explode(df$user)) %>%  select("created_at", "a.utc_offset")
```

but i get the error:

```
Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "DataFrame"
```

I cannot find any help for this.

Comment: why are you trying to `explode`? From what I have seen with SparkR, the `SELECT` statement should normalize the data for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible. `SparkDataFrame` doesn't implement the same interface as `data.frame`.

If you want to use `dplyr` with Spark you should use [`sparklyr`](https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr), not SparkR.

With SparkR use [`SparkR::withColumn`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/):

```
withColumn(df, "a", explode(df$user))
```

or [`SparkR::mutate`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/).