# Spark SQL explode referencing

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

It is not clear to me how can you refer to the exploded column in the same subquery, and I am not sure what to search for to get more explanation.

```
SELECT explode(kit) exploded,
    exploded [0]
FROM tabla
```

When we are referring from the outer query, it is super clear because the exploded column already exists.
What am I missing?

```
select exploded [0] from
(SELECT explode(kit) exploded
FROM tabla)
```

[image]

Comment: check lateral view, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37350297/9510729)

Comment: @jxc lateral view is clear because it is in the FROM section, and in SQL FROM part is executed first, and the SELECT only after it.  But in the above case, this order is broken

Comment: interesting question, I think it's some features with the Generator, I tried `json_tuple` and it also works.

Comment: If you run your query `spark.sql("...").explain(extended=True)`, you will find that the Generators are actually run as Sub-query even if you put it in the SELECT list. it should be doing the same as using lateral view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The physical plans of these two queries, and also the lateral view query, are identical. Apparently, the analyzed logical plan of the first query is identical to the lateral view query. After optimization, the logical plans of all three queries became identical.

---

Create dataframe:

```
df = spark.range(1).selectExpr("array(array(1,2),array(3,4)) kit")
```

First query:

```
spark.sql('select explode(kit) exploded, exploded[0] from tabla').explain(True)
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'Project ['explode('kit) AS exploded#308, unresolvedalias('exploded[0], None)]
+- 'UnresolvedRelation [tabla]

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
exploded: array<int>, exploded[0]: int
Project [exploded#309, exploded#309[0] AS exploded[0]#310]
+- Generate explode(kit#292), false, [exploded#309]
   +- SubqueryAlias tabla
      +- Project [array(array(1, 2), array(3, 4)) AS kit#292]
         +- Range (0, 1, step=1, splits=Some(24))

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Project [exploded#309, exploded#309[0] AS exploded[0]#310]
+- Generate explode([[1,2],[3,4]]), [0], false, [exploded#309]
   +- Project [[[1,2],[3,4]] AS kit#292]
      +- Range (0, 1, step=1, splits=Some(24))

== Physical Plan ==
*(2) Project [exploded#309, exploded#309[0] AS exploded[0]#310]
+- Generate explode([[1,2],[3,4]]), false, [exploded#309]
   +- *(1) Project [[[1,2],[3,4]] AS kit#292]
      +- *(1) Range (0, 1, step=1, splits=24)
```

Second query: using subquery

```
spark.sql('select exploded[0] from (select explode(kit) exploded from tabla)').explain(True)
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'Project [unresolvedalias('exploded[0], None)]
+- 'SubqueryAlias __auto_generated_subquery_name
   +- 'Project ['explode('kit) AS exploded#313]
      +- 'UnresolvedRelation [tabla]

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
exploded[0]: int
Project [exploded#314[0] AS exploded[0]#315]
+- SubqueryAlias __auto_generated_subquery_name
   +- Project [exploded#314]
      +- Generate explode(kit#292), false, [exploded#314]
         +- SubqueryAlias tabla
            +- Project [array(array(1, 2), array(3, 4)) AS kit#292]
               +- Range (0, 1, step=1, splits=Some(24))

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Project [exploded#314[0] AS exploded[0]#315]
+- Generate explode([[1,2],[3,4]]), [0], false, [exploded#314]
   +- Project [[[1,2],[3,4]] AS kit#292]
      +- Range (0, 1, step=1, splits=Some(24))

== Physical Plan ==
*(2) Project [exploded#314[0] AS exploded[0]#315]
+- Generate explode([[1,2],[3,4]]), false, [exploded#314]
   +- *(1) Project [[[1,2],[3,4]] AS kit#292]
      +- *(1) Range (0, 1, step=1, splits=24)
```

Third query: using `lateral view`

```
spark.sql('select exploded[0] from tabla lateral view explode(kit) as exploded').explain(True)
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'Project [unresolvedalias('exploded[0], None)]
+- 'Generate 'explode('kit), false, as, ['exploded]
   +- 'UnresolvedRelation [tabla]

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
exploded[0]: int
Project [exploded#353[0] AS exploded[0]#354]
+- Generate explode(kit#292), false, as, [exploded#353]
   +- SubqueryAlias tabla
      +- Project [array(array(1, 2), array(3, 4)) AS kit#292]
         +- Range (0, 1, step=1, splits=Some(24))

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Project [exploded#353[0] AS exploded[0]#354]
+- Generate explode([[1,2],[3,4]]), [0], false, as, [exploded#353]
   +- Project [[[1,2],[3,4]] AS kit#292]
      +- Range (0, 1, step=1, splits=Some(24))

== Physical Plan ==
*(2) Project [exploded#353[0] AS exploded[0]#354]
+- Generate explode([[1,2],[3,4]]), false, [exploded#353]
   +- *(1) Project [[[1,2],[3,4]] AS kit#292]
      +- *(1) Range (0, 1, step=1, splits=24)
```